# How to manage the lot of callback from the retrofit response?

Tags: retrofit

While getting the response from the single activity we have to write a lots of callback and have to get these code's **onResponse()** and **onFailure()**. Is there any manageable way so that we can override single callback with the only single **onFailure()** and  **onReponse()**?

for example

```
  private void fetchMoviesFromWeb(int pageNumber, String moviesCategories) {
        Callback<MoviesInfo> moviesInfoCallback = new Callback<MoviesInfo>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response<MoviesInfo> response) {

                }


            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {

            }
        };
        retrofitManager.getMoviesInfo(moviesCategories, pageNumber, Constants.API_KEY, moviesInfoCallback);
    }

/************** **********/
private void fetchMoviesCommentFromWeb()
{

 Callback<MoviesComment> moviesInfoCallback = new Callback<MoviesComment>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Response<MoviesComment> response) {

                    }


                @Override
                public void onFailure(Throwable t) {

                }
            };
            retrofitManager.getMoviesInfo(moviesCategories, pageNumber, Constants.API_KEY, moviesInfoCallback);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make an abstract callback implementing both methods as no-op and extend from that callback when you only need one of the two methods:

```
public abstract class AbstractCallback<T> implements Callback<T> {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
        // ignore by default
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Response<T> response) throws IOException {
        // ignore by default
    }
}

Callback<MoviesComment> moviesInfoCallback = new AbstractCallback<MoviesComment>() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
        // only do something with the failure
    }
}
```